# Twilio - Use Gather DTMF with Stream

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, ivr, dtmf

I am trying to build a system that captures my media stream when I call into a twilio inbound number. If the user presses the # key, I would like to disconnect the call.
 In my nodejs code, I handled the answer call request as:

```
res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Say> Welcome to XYZ </Say>
      <Gather input="dtmf" finishOnKey="#" timeout="60" action="/completed">
          <Stream name="description" url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Gather>
    </Response>
  `);
```

and my completed method is declared as:

```
app.get("/completed", (req, res) => res.send(`<Hangup />`));
```

But the call waits for 60 seconds and media doesn't streams to wss event, though disconnect on pressing # key. Whereas if I write

```
res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Say> Welcome to XYZ </Say>
      <Start>
         <Stream name="description" url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Start>
      <Pause length="15" />
      <Gather input="dtmf" finishOnKey="#" timeout="60" action="/completed">
      </Gather>
    </Response>
  `);
```

then, the media stream to wss connection but dtmf doesn't works. Any suggestion to solve this scenario?

Comment: What is Media Streams being used for during these 60 seconds, can you clarify? Maybe there is another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Media streams are used for text-to-speech conversions and using my custom apis for the data analytics